# Size inside a sheet being reported incorrectly

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var size:CGSize = .zero
  @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
      ZStack {
        // this just serves to know the view size
        Color.red
          .readSize {size in
            print ("size of view = ", size)
          }
          .onAppear{
            Task {@MainActor in
              try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC * UInt64(1))
              withAnimation {
                showSheet.toggle()
              }
            }
          }
          .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            ContentView()
              .onAppear{
                print ("this is the sheet")
              }
          }
      }
    }
}


struct ViewSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
  static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
  static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
    value = nextValue()
  }
}


extension View {
  public func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
    background(
      GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
        Color.clear
          .preference(key: ViewSizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
      }
    )
    .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizePreferenceKey.self,
                        perform: onChange)
    
  }
}
```

I am using preference keys to know the size of a view, by using `Color.red` to do the dirty work for me. I am trying to avoid using `GeometryReader`, even with the `.background()` modifier because it did not solve my problem and created others.

So, this view loads, reports its size and calls itself. This will be an infinite loop, but just serves to illustrate my point.

The first time this code runs, the size for the iPhone 15 simulator is reported as being `(393.0, 749.0)` but from the second time on, `ContentView` is shown inside a sheet, which is smaller, at least in height. Remember that the sheet does not cover the whole screen vertically. Even so, the reported size is barely the same, just 10pt less in high, a value that is far from real.

What kind of code can report the real available size inside a sheet on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sheet *does* report a different size. I think you may have confused the issue by using the same view with recursion.

Here's some simplified code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .readSize {size in
                    print ("size of view = ", size)
                }
                .task {
                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC)
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                    SheetView()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .readSize {size in
                    print ("size of sheet view = ", size)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    public func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: ViewSizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizePreferenceKey.self,
                            perform: onChange)
    }
}
```

Here, on the iPhone 15 simulator, the `ContentView` reports a height of `759` and the `SheetView` reports a height of `749`.

If you also ignore safe areas, the difference becomes even greater, at `852` vs `783`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var size:CGSize = .zero
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .readSize {size in
                    print ("size of view = ", size)
                }
                .task {
                    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: NSEC_PER_SEC)
                    showSheet.toggle()
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                    SheetView()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct SheetView: View {
    
    @State var size:CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .readSize {size in
                    print ("size of sheet view = ", size)
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    public func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: ViewSizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(ViewSizePreferenceKey.self,
                            perform: onChange)
    }
}
```